# cairo draw line and text, then display PNG file so that old objects don't get erased

Tags: linux, cairo

If I draw lines, show texts and display the image (PNG icon) in the area, the previously drawn lines and text are erased, and finally, only the PNG image is displayed. The old ones shouldn't be erased.

The code for drawing a rectangle line is below:

```
cairo_set_line_width (cr, BATTERY_RECTANGLE_WIDTH*3);    
cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 0.0, 0.95, 0.95, 1);    
cairo_stroke (cr);    
/* text */    
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 0.78, 0.94, 0.0, 1.0);    
cairo_select_font_face (cr, "cairo:serif", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);    
cairo_show_text (cr, "TEST");
```

My code for displaying a PNG image is below:

```
image = cairo_image_source_create_from_png("test.png");    
cairo_set_source_sourface (cr, image, PREVIEW_WIDTH + (APP_WINDOW_WIDTH-PREVIEW_WIDTH)/2+10,(APP_WINDOW_HEIGHT - PREVIEW_HEIHGT)/2 + 100);    
cairo_paint(cr);
```

My question is: What should I change to display text, rectangle lines and PNG images in same area?

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You are first drawing some lines / rectangles / text. Afterwards you want to draw one PNG. And you want the PNG to appear below the already drawn things? Why can't you first draw the image and the lines afterwards?

Comment: Hi Uli, Thank you for answering, I want to show PNG icons on background rectangles and lines which is background GUI. So, I drawed background GUIs and then PNG icons, but when PNG icons were drawed, background GUIs were erased.

Answer (score 0):

`cairo_paint()` "copies everything". Try `cairo_rectangle(cr, x, y, width, height); cairo_fill(cr);` instead (I am not quite sure which values you want for the rectangle).

Conceptually, patterns in cairo are infinitely large. I *guess* you PNG file does not have an alpha channel and is then padded with a white background to infinity.

Comment: thank you for warming guide !. It works !